# How to get the sum of timedelta in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

Python: How to get the sum of timedelta?

Eg. I just got a lot of timedelta object, and now I want the sum. That's it!

Comment: ???? dont understand the question. Do you have a formula ?

Comment: What do you do if you have a lot of integer objects, and you want the sum? What have you tried? What happened when you tried?

Comment: my guess is that if you have tds = [ timedelta(), timedelta(), timedelta(), ...], he wants to know how to do sum(tds). This is not possible as is, as sum kind starts with 0 and hence try to do 0+timedelta(). You can of course do it with some basic loop duration = timedelta(0); for td in tds: duration += td

Answer (score 14, accepted):

datetime combine method allows you to combine time with a delta

```
datetime.combine(date.today(), time()) + timedelta(hours=2)
```

timedelta can be combined using usual '+' operator

```
>>> timedelta(hours=3) 
datetime.timedelta(0, 10800)
>>> timedelta(hours=2)
datetime.timedelta(0, 7200)
>>>
>>> timedelta(hours=3) + timedelta(hours=2)
datetime.timedelta(0, 18000)
>>>
```

You can read the datetime module docs and a very good simple introduction at

- http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/datetime/

Answer (score 62):

To add timedeltas you can use the builtin operator `+`:

```
result = timedelta1 + timedelta2
```

To add a lot of timedeltas you can use sum:

```
result = sum(timedeltas, datetime.timedelta())
```

Or reduce:

```
import operator
result = reduce(operator.add, timedeltas)
```

Comment: Hmmm, I would expect the sum function to work too, but it appears not for me on 2.7.3. The following fails: ``sum([datetime.timedelta(1), datetime.timedelta(0, 14700)])``.

Comment: @pelson: You are missing the second parameter. `sum([datetime.timedelta(1), datetime.timedelta(0, 14700)], datetime.timedelta())` gives `datetime.timedelta(1, 14700)`.

Comment: To guide others that might be searching for this, the error you get without the second parameter is ``TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'type' and 'datetime.timedelta'``. And the official docs that explain why this second argument is needed are [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum).

Comment: nice answer using reduce.

Comment: python3 users will need `from functools import reduce`

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list of timedelta objects, you could try:

datetime.timedelta(seconds=sum(td.total_seconds() for td in list_of_deltas))

Answer (score 1):

As this "just works", I assume this question lacks some detail...

Just like this:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.timedelta(seconds=10) + datetime.timedelta(hours=5)
datetime.timedelta(0, 18010)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that by "sum" he means that he wants the value of the sum in a primitive type (eg integer) rather than a datetime object.

Note that you can always use the `dir` function to reflect on an object, returning a list of its methods and attributes.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> time_sum=datetime.timedelta(seconds=10) + datetime.timedelta(hours=5)
>>> time_sum
datetime.timedelta(0, 18010)
>>> dir(time_sum)
['__abs__', '__add__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__div__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__floordiv__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__neg__', '__new__', '__nonzero__', '__pos__', '__radd__', '__rdiv__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rfloordiv__', '__rmul__', '__rsub__', '__setattr__', '__str__', '__sub__', 'days', 'max', 'microseconds', 'min', 'resolution', 'seconds']
```

So in this case, it looks like we probably want seconds.

```
>>> time_sum.seconds
18010
```

Which looks right to me:

```
>>> 5*60*60 + 10
18010
```

Comment: This doesn't work for timedeltas with a `days` component: `datetime.timedelta(days=3, hours=5, seconds=10).seconds -> 18010`. It should be 277210s ((3*24*60*60) + (5*60*60) + 10).

Comment: Better solution: `time_sum.total_seconds()`

(includes seconds from the days component as well)

http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds

Answer (score 0):

(*Edit:* Assuming that by "sum timedelta" you mean "convert a timedelta to int seconds".)

This is very inefficient, but it is simple:

```
int((datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0) + myTimeDelta).strftime("%s"))
```

This converts a Unix timestamp (`0`) into a datetime object, adds your delta to it, and then converts back to a Unix time. Since Unix time counts seconds, this is the number of seconds your timedelta represented.

Comment: that's completely irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Not necessarily. I share Goladus's interpretation - that user469652 wants to sum the components of a timedelta into a single primitive type, such as seconds. That's certainly what I was looking for when I found this question.

Comment: Better solution: `myTimeDelta.total_seconds()`

http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds