# Get average of times

Tags: python

Given the following list:

```
times = [datetime.timedelta(0, 1, 256273), datetime.timedelta(0, 0, 910417), datetime.timedelta(0, 0, 388175)]
```

How would I get the average of times? Doing the following gives me an error:

```
avg = (float(sum(times)) / len(times))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

Comment: And what's the error?

Comment: Duplicate for part A: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4049825/3001761

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two problems here:

- `sum()` starts out the summing with an integer `0`. You cannot add a `timedelta()` object to an integer, so you get an error:

  ```
  >>> import datetime
  >>> times = [datetime.timedelta(0, 1, 256273), datetime.timedelta(0, 0, 910417), datetime.timedelta(0, 0, 388175)]
  >>> sum(times)
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'datetime.timedelta'
  ```
- Even if you could just use `sum()` outright, you cannot convert a `timedelta()` object to a `float()` by passing it to the `float()` function:

  ```
  >>> float(datetime.timedelta())
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
  ```

You need to tell `sum()` to start with an empty `timedelta` (start at `timedelta(0)`) and use the `timedelta.total_seconds()` function to get a floating point number:

```
>>> sum(times, datetime.timedelta())
datetime.timedelta(0, 2, 554865)
>>> sum(times, datetime.timedelta()).total_seconds()
2.554865
>>> sum(times, datetime.timedelta()).total_seconds() / len(times)
0.8516216666666666
```

You can omit the `.total_seconds()` part and get another `timedelta()` object:

```
>>> sum(times, datetime.timedelta()) / len(times)
datetime.timedelta(0, 0, 851621)
```

which is going to be more accurate. You can always call `.total_seconds()` *after* the division:

```
>>> (sum(times, datetime.timedelta()) / len(times)).total_seconds()
0.851621
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use list comprehension to get a list of `floats`, which can be summed:

```
avg = sum([t.total_seconds() for t in times]) / len(times)

# avg == 0.851621666667
```

But as Martijn said, it is more accurate to sum `timedelta` objects together, starting from an empty one.